# Подсчёт кол-во повторений символа в строке без if

Tags: c#, wpf, строки, char

Можно ли как-то это реализовать проверку без использования if?

```
         int n = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i<=TextLable.Text.Length; i++) {
            if (TextLabel.Text[i] == '#') 
            {
            n++; //узнаём кол-во повторений символа '#'
            } 
         }
        //int n = TextLabel.Text.Count(f => f == '#'); //?
```

Comment: И где здесь `if`?

Comment: Имею ввиду, чтоб не использовать if для отлавливания символа.

Comment: Можно так делать: int cou = str.Count(f => (f == '+'))

Comment: этот код не работает? пример или несколько примеров такой строки покажите и что именно надо посчитать? всего количество символов или самую длинную последовательность, или количество последовательностей, что именно?

Comment: @Виктор Это проходя стразу всю строку, а мне нужно поэлементно за цикл

Comment: @aepot Кол-во повторений символа поэлементно за цикл

Comment: `n += 1 - Math.Sign(TextLabel.Text[i] ^ '#')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
int n = 0;
char[] charArr = TextLabel.Text.ToCharArray();  
foreach (char ch in charArr)  
{  
    n = (ch == '#') ? n+1 : n;
}
```

На всякий случай, без цикла

```
n = TextLabel.Text.Count(f => (f == '#'))
n = TextLabel.Text.Where(x => (x == '#')).Count();

foreach (char c in TextLabel.Text)
{
    n = (c == '#') ? n+1 : n;
}
```

// Здесь шаг задать можно

```
string myString = TextLabel.Text;
for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
{
    n = (myString[i] == myChar) ? n+1 : n;
}
```

Comment: @ Ага, значит в `n = TextLabel.Text.Count(f => (f == '#'))` нельзя использовать шаг цикла (**i**)?

Comment: Для этого примера шаг = 1

Comment: @wasdalt а зачем Вам считать повторяющиеся символы с шагом?

Comment: зачем использовать тернарник там где только один вариант ветвления? пустая трата ресурсов. `.ToCharArray()` зачем? тоже бесполезная работа, делайте `foreach` сразу по строке. Тернарник этот тот же `if`, только сокращенный.

Comment: Как вам такое? Вообще без ветвления `n += 1 - Math.Sign(c ^ '#');`, ну относительно

Comment: @aepot Я просто показал варианты реализации(не все конечно). "Тернарник" - показал как без if (явного) - что просили, то и реализовал. "Как вам такое?" - я же не Илон Маск ;))) Красиво, но не однозначно

Comment: Что неоднозначного?

Comment: Не все вникнут сразу,  тут же вроде как для обучения вопрос был.